# Rails nested looping through tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have 2 tables = tasks and taskstatuses

In a Task index view, I would like to loop through the taskstatuses and for each taskstatus display the associated tasks.

I'm trying to do this in a file called tasks/index3.html.erb

This is the index code that doesn't work:

```
<% @taskstatuses.each_with_index do |taskstatus, index| %>
```

I tried adding this to Tasks controller:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController

# GET /taskstatuses
 def index
  @taskstatuses = Taskstatus.all
 end
```

But, I get "You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!  Error evaluating nil.each_with_index

Sure would appreciate help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your index action isn't being called.  Likely,  when you ask to render index3,  there is no index3 action,  but there is an index3.html.erb,  so that view is getting rendered without any intervening action.

you could do something as simple as adding:

```
def index3
  @taskstatuses = Taskstatus.all
end
```

There are probably better ways, i.e.

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :loadtasks, :only=>[:index,:index3]
  def loadtasks
    @taskstatuses = Taskstatus.all
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks - really like the 2nd one!